# Voting on comments should not require using mouse

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, opera, keyboard

I'm using Opera with only a keyboard, without the mouse. Opera includes support of

```
Shift+ arrows
```

to navigate over active elements (such as links,input fields,clickable images) on the page. Current element is outlined with blue box and I can activate is with "Enter" button

The comment upvote button is not active (it shows only when mouse is over the comment).

So, I request a feature: not to hide comment upvote button, just show it in gray.

Answer (score 5):

Until this gets implemented (if it gets implemented at all), I have a simple [userscript](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/) to show all the comment flags/upvotes: http://so.piskvor.org/101707/fakemouseover.user.js

```
function fakemouse_with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

fakemouse_with_jquery(function($) {
    $('.comment').each(function(idx,elem){
        jel = $(elem);
        jel.trigger('mouseover');
        jel.unbind('mouseleave');
        jel.removeAttr('id');
    });
    $('.comments').removeAttr('id');
    $('.comments tr').removeAttr('class');
});
```

---

For some reason, Opera's keyboard nav picks up on some IDs and classes; removing them seems to help (warning: the above code has been [shotgun-debugged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) in an attempt to stop Opera from focusing on the whole comment box - with partial success: *some* upvotes/flags are now easier to reach, focus on commenter's username and go left - in many cases this gets you to the "flag comment" link, depending on how the comment is flowed)

Comment: Hm. Even with the links showing, it's still a PITA to get to them with the keyboard navigation.